# Cocoa counterpart to Windows' SetTimer

Tags: c++, cocoa, timer

Is there any equivalent function on OS X to SetTimer in Windows? I'm using C++.

So I'm writing a plugin for some software, and I need to have a function called periodically. On Windows I just pass the address of the function to SetTimer() and it will be called at a given interval.
Is there an easy way to do this on OS X?
It should be as minimalistic as possible. I didn't really find anything non-fancy on the web, there was something about a huge framework and another solution using a second thread that is sleeping the other time, but I think there should be an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the [Boost Asio library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html).  The class [deadline_timer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/deadline_timer.html) works on all platforms.  Just use [bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/bind/bind.html) to attach a function to [async_wait](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/async_wait.html) and call [expires_from_now](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/expires_from_now.html).

```
io_service io;
deadline_timer timer(io);

void handler()
{
    static int second_counter = 0;
    cout << second_counter++ << endl;

    timer.expires_from_now(posix_time::seconds(1));    
    timer.async_wait(bind(&handler));
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    handler();

    io.run();
}
```

It'll take a little time to get your head around Asio (especially since the documentation is...patchy) but it's well worth learning.

Comment: Hmm, don't quite understand the 0 rating (though I'm grateful the answer was accepted!)?  The author explicitly mentioned they were using C++ (not Cocoa, like some of the answers assumed) and this is the best way I know of to set a timer in that language...

Answer (score 4):

In Cocoa, a typical call goes something like this;

```
NSTimer *repeatingTimer=  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeIntervalInSecs target:objectImplementingFunction selector:@selector(nameOfYourFunction:) userInfo:argToYourFunction repeats:YES];
```

which causes a timer to be placed on the current runloop.  Whenever the timer fires it will call your function.

If you later want to cancel the timer call

```
[repeatingTimer invalidate];
```

which removes it from the runloop.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) class.

Answer (score 1):

If you want simplicity, which don't you just use `alarm()`?

Set a signal handler for `SIGALRM`, and then call `alarm()` to ask the OS to generate the signal after a delay. There's an example [here](http://docs.linux.cz/programming/c/unix_examples/alarm.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have a little tutorial on my page

http://cocoa-coding.de/timer/nstimer.html

It's only in German but I am sure you will understand the code samples.

Answer (score 0):

The [Poco C++ library](http://pocoproject.org/) provides a cross-platform [Timer class](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=nl&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc#0a1G51JYx4Q/trunk/ofxCppGlue/libs/Poco/include/Poco/Timer.h).